# How to detect if TextView contains SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

How can one find out if `TextView` contains `SpannableStringBuilder` and not plain text?
I need to change text size of `TextView`, but it is different if it contains plain text or span.

```
TextView textView1;
textView1.setText("BlahBlahBlah");

TextView textView2;
final SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);
                                                        final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255,255,255));
                                                        sb.setSpan(fcs,  bookname.length(),title.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView2.setText(sb);
```

Now I need a method like this : **textView1.hasSpans()**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `instanceOf`

```
 final CharSequence text = textView.getText();
 if(text instanceof Spannable){
    ...
```

I'm using it in `setFilter` so no reason why it will not work over here